# rapidjson : How to get value from reference document

Tags: rapidjson

I need to get value from the rapidjson document (reference).

Below is the code:

```
Document *jsonDocument;  
Value& data = jsonDocument["data"];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that jsonDocument is a pointer to Document. To call the `operator[]`, you may:

```
Value& data = (*jsonDocument)["data"]
```